# Find all records in a table where the most recent record in a join table has a column which is not equal to one is this table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Image the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id INT,
  price INT
);

CREATE TABLE item_price_history (
  id INT,
  item_id INT,
  price INT
);
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO items (id, price) VALUES (1, 199);
INSERT INTO items (id, price) VALUES (2, 159);
INSERT INTO items (id, price) VALUES (3, 129);
INSERT INTO items (id, price) VALUES (4, 119);

INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (1, 1, 249);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (2, 1, 239);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (3, 1, 229);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (4, 1, 199);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (5, 2, 299);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (6, 2, 259);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (7, 2, 159);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (8, 2, 109);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (9, 3, 129);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (10, 4, 159);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (11, 4, 119);
INSERT INTO item_price_history (id, item_id, price) VALUES (13, 4, 99);
```

Now I would like to find all the `items` for which the `items.price` is not equal to the most recent `item_price_history.price` (`id DESC`) in `item_price_history`. In this case that should produce item with id `3` and `4`. As their prices does NOT match the most recent price in `item_price_history`.

I did the following which works:

```
SELECT items.id, items.price i_price, item_price_history.id, item_price_history.price as ih_price 
    FROM items
    LEFT JOIN item_price_history ON item_price_history.item_id = items.id 
        AND item_price_history.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM item_price_history WHERE item_id = items.id)
    WHERE items.price != item_price_history.price
    LIMIT 100
```

However I have a table of about 2 million rows in `items` and 20 million rows in `item_price_history` which I need to scan through, so performance is important.

How would I write such a query in a more performant way e.g by using `DISTINCT ON` or something?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPkdHvvzS2tmZq2vKUwgNi/2

Comment: Run the query less often, but don't throw away all but the first 100 rows.

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the real dataset, and the indexes you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query to do it in bulk with DISTINCT ON:

```
SELECT items.id, items.price i_price, item_price_history.id, item_price_history.price as ih_price
  from items 
  join (select distinct on (item_id) id, item_id, price from item_price_history order by item_id desc, id desc) item_price_history
on item_price_history.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.price != item_price_history.price;
```

It should be well supported by an index `on item_price_history (item_id , id, price);` which will let it do a presorted index-only scan.